# Unexpected token u when trying to parse a JSON array from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a PHP script which is used for a POST request which returns (echos) the array:

```
array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(32) "The item was successfully saved"
  ["newItemId"]=>
  int(9)
  ["newCustomFieldIds"]=>
  string(3) "[9]"
}
```

My AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'updateItemDetails.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            ...
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response); //correct
            console.log(response['newCustomFieldIds']); //undefined
            console.log(JSON.parse(response['newCustomFieldIds'])); //unexpected token u
    });
```

The first console.log produces:

```
{"message":"The item was successfully saved","newItemId":9,"newCustomFieldIds":"[9]"}
```

which is as expected. However, the second one gives `undefined`.

So, when I JSON.parse, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`! What I'm trying to do is to get the `"[9]"` to a real array, ie. `[9]`.

I don't understand this. `newCustomFieldIds` definitely exists, because when logging the `response`, I can see it -- so why doesn't the `console.log(response['newCustomFieldIds'])` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse `response`:

```
JSON.parse(response).newCustomFieldIds
```

If you want to convert the string `"[9]"` to an array, you need to call `JSON.parse` twice:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response).newCustomFieldIds)
```

However, **the better solution** would be to encode the value of `newCustomFieldIds` as an array in the first place, i.e. the JSON should contain `"newCustomFieldIds": [9]`.

---

Since you know that `response['newCustomFieldIds']` returns `undefined`, it doesn't make sense to try `JSON.parse(response['newCustomFieldIds'])`. It's the same as `JSON.parse("undefined")`, but `undefined` is not valid JSON.

Comment: hmmm now I get `Unexpected token a`..!? (when I parse twice)

Comment: Then `response` isn't the value you claim it to be: https://jsfiddle.net/bu63quzb/ . The general solution is pretty straightforward: If you have a string that contains JSON, call `JSON.parse`. Read [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) to learn more about how to access objects to get the value you want.

Comment: That means the `response` also contains `"array(3) => ..."` which is not valid JSON. It seems you have a `var_dump` somewhere in your PHP code. That output is also sent to the client as part of the response. Remove it.

Comment: oh! you're right!! I have it a few changes back which is what I use to echo the data back! I should have removed that ages ago! Thank you so much!! :D

Comment: And I think it's worth the effort to encode it as an array in the first place, so I'll probably go back and change anything I need to to do that. Thanks again :)